# How to fix WordPress kses error and fatal error handler

Tags: wordpress, formatting

I'm new at making website. Even I only know Html Coding. I'm running a website using WordPress, but it is facing problem everyday at same time. Everyday at the same time site is showing Http 500 error.

So as I don't know any kind of coding, every day I have to delete WordPress from my site then again have to install it then I have to restore website using Updraftplus. But I want to fix this oroblem.

I have an option in my cPanel called "Errors". I find this error from there.

[image: Here Is The Image Of Which Problem I'm Facing.]

I copied what there was said:

1st error:

> [Mon Dec 23 03:46:44.895719 2019] [lsapi:error] [pid 1014092:tid 47766993704704] [client 141.8.188.1:46957] [host gokumovie.com] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function esc_url() in /home/gokumovi/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php:190\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/gokumovi/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(147): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, false)\n#1 /home/gokumovi/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(52): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, false)\n#2 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /home/gokumovi/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php on line 190\n

2nd error :

> Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_kses_normalize_entities() in /home/gokumovi/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:4316\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/gokumovi/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(190): esc_url('https://wordpre...')\n#1 /home/gokumovi/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(147): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, false)\n#2 /home/gokumovi/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(52): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, false)\n#3 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle()\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /home/gokumovi/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4316\n

Comment: This type of errors usually caused by theme or plugin function conflicts please try deactivating all your plugins and activate them one by one to see which one is causing the error. if that doesn't help try to switch in one of default theme..

Comment: So I have to wait until next time this problem occurs ? Then I Have To Follow Theses Steps ?

Comment: if the problem is not present right now then you have to wait until problem occurs again